# maven credentials from settings.xml is not used

Tags: maven

For my repository URL I am able to login in my browser using the user id and password that I have in the `settings.xml`. Also I am sure that the `settings.xml` is picked up. But I am getting  `Error code 401, Unauthorized`, when the project is being build.

Part of my `pom.xml`

```
 <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>myid</id>
                <url>REPO URL</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
```

Part of my `settings.xml`

```
<servers>
     <server>
       <id>myid</id>
       <username>user_id</username>
       <password>password</password>
     </server>
   </servers>
```

Comment: Could you post the result of `mvn -X compile`?

Comment: run it from where..? I didn't install maven. It's just there in eclipse.

Comment: Isn't `<repositories/>` where code gets download from?  To upload, don't you need `<distributionManagement><repository>...</repository><snapshotRepository>...</snapshotRepository></distributionManagement>`?

Comment: @AJNeufeld I tihnk the OP needs to authenticate to download their artifact.

Comment: In Eclipse, you need to go under "Run > Run configuration" Create a Maven build, call it whatever you want, tick "Debug Output" and in "Goals, write "compile".

Comment: @Tunaki Password for download?  What?  Code wants to be free! :^D

Answer (score -2):

This is probably not the solution you are looking for, but "gradle" will do what you want.  Of course, it means converting your project's build system from "maven" to "gradle", which could be as easy as running `gradle -q init` in your project directory, or as hard as getting a herd of stampeding <strike>elephants</strike>developers to change directions.

> **23.6.4.1. Accessing password protected Maven repositories**
>
> To access a Maven repository which uses basic authentication, you specify the username and password to use when you define the repository:
>
> Example 23.31. Accessing password protected Maven repository
>
> build.gradle
>
> ```
> repositories {
>     maven {
>         credentials {
>             username 'user'
>             password 'password'
>         }
>         url "http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2"
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> It is advisable to keep your username and password in `gradle.properties` rather than directly in the build file.